# Ornamental scot pine dying

Tags: pines

Purchased two of these about three months ago. One is doing great. The other seems to be dying quickly. About a month ago I notice it starting having dead needles. Each week it's progressively worse. I have noticed a lot of sooty mold on the leaves of both trees. Once the needles completely brown, the smaller branches are so brittle they just snap away. Not sure what to do to save this tree.enter image description here[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you have a period of extreme heat recently? Potted conifers seem to react like this too extreme heat, best is to water it more frequently and mist it during these periods. Or put it temporarily in the shade .